# Rails: how to select_rows with fields names (mysql)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am looking for a way to get a result set for a mysql query that is similar to the output of ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows but also includes the result's columns names as the first element.

For example:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows_with_fields("SELECT id,name FROM users")
     => [["id", "name"], ["1","amy"],["2","bob"],["3","cam"]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select_rows_with_fields:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class Mysql2Adapter
      def select_rows_with_fields(sql)
        result = execute(sql)
        rows = result.to_a
        rows.unshift(result.fields)
      end
    end
  end
end
```